# Network switching in HTML JS. Please support

Tags: metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Please support in adding network switch for my JS file in HTML code. Just one example will be sufficient.

```
var bep20Button = document.querySelector('.network-bep20-token'); 
var matic20Button = document.querySelector('.network-matic-token'); 

function changeToBepNetwork() {
  bep20Button.classList.add("network-active-tab"); 
  matic20Button.classList.remove("network-active-tab"); 
  tokenCurrency.innerHTML = "BNB"; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here it goes. The function below uses metamask and switches the network to the one received in the function parameter. Note that the network id must be passed in `0x` format, for example, `0x1` for Ethereum mainnet.

```js
// switches network to the one provided. Must be in 0x format 
const switchNetwork = async (chainId) => {
  await window.ethereum.request({
    method: 'wallet_switchEthereumChain',
        params: [{ chainId: chainId}],
  })
  // refresh
  window.location.reload()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the wallet_switchEthereumChain method from web3.js.
You can find an example of how to use it [here](https://www.0xdev.co/how-to-switch-network-metamask-wallet-web3/).